# Kubernetes global variables (for all namespaces)

Tags: kubernetes

I need to create and mantain some global variables accessible for applications running in all namespaces, because some tools/apps are standard in my dev cluster.

**For example:**

- APM ENDPOINT
- APM User/pass
- RabbitMQ endpoint
- MongoDB endpoint

For any reason, when i change/migrate any global variable, i want to change one time for all running applications in cluster (just needed restart pod), and if a create an "global" configmap and read in envFrom, i need to change/update the configmap in all namespaces.

Someone have an idea to do this? I thinked to use Hashicorp vault with specific role for global environments, but i need to adapt all applications to use Vault, and maybe have better idea.

Thanks

Comment: Managing these things globally across all namespaces is a bit contrary to the design of Kubernetes namespaces. Typically namespaces are "access boundaries" where e.g. a team manage the resources within one or a few namespaces - not across many.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. But in development cluster with a almost 100 namespaces that share same environment variables, is very dificult update some values that are standard in all namespaces.

Comment: You are referring to three "endpoints" - it sounds like that could be handled by a DNS name?

Comment: Yes, for endpoints i can use an DNS value instead of service name in k8s, but for user/pass o need another solution. Maybe Vault is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no in-built solution in Kubernetes for it except for [creating a ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-a-configmap), and use  `envFrom`  to define all of the ConfigMap's data as Pod environment variables, which will indeed require to update them separately for each namespace. So using HashiCorp Vault is a better solution here; one more option here can be trying to customize env with Kubernetes addons [like this](https://github.com/EmberStack/kubernetes-reflector).

Comment: Thanks @anarxz!!

Reflector its amazin solution, i really didn't know!! I can use too for create docker registry secret and apply for all namespaces :)

thanks a lot!